# How to read from github actions cache without writing to it

Tags: github

I'm using github actions cache for persisting remotely downloaded dependencies from tests across CI executions. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows

The issue I'm having is that I only want the action write to the cache when it's running on the `push` action on the `master` branch. If the action is a `pull_request`, I'd like it to read from the cache, but not write to it.

The reason for this is that caches that are originated from master are mostly reusable for any PR, but caches generated from a PR may not be super useful for other CI invocations because the code is yet to be reviewed and the developer may be trying out things which may just mess up the cache for other invocations.

Right now I'm doing something like this

```
- name: Cache packages

  uses: actions/cache@v3
  with:
    key: 'cache-${{ github.event_name }}'
    restore-keys: |
        cache-push
    path: |
      /path/to/cache
```

This way I have 2 cache keys, one for PRs and one for master, master will always use the cache from he previous master invocation because it will only match `cache-push`, but prs will use a different key, `cache-pull_request` and fallback to `cache-push` if it doesnt exist. This way master pushes never use a cache that was generated from a pr, only caches that were generated from the previous master push.

Ideally I'd like the `cache-pull_request` key to not even exist and just have PRs use `cache-push` but not write to it at the end of the execution. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Github Actions now [officially supports this](https://github.com/actions/cache/pull/1035) as of version 3.2.0!

Original comment:

I've been looking for the same thing and unfortunately it does not seem to be possible. There are open PRs and issues in the repo on Github

https://github.com/actions/cache/pull/489

So until it get merged or implemented in some other way it is not a possibility with the official Github cache workflow.

I also noticed that this PR had been closed

https://github.com/actions/cache/pull/474

The author closed it himself due to inactivity, but forked it to another repo and implemented it there. See https://github.com/MartijnHols/actions-cache

I have not used this repo myself but it might be worth checking out

Answer (score 2):

Check [actions/cache/restore@v3](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/restore/README.md) and [actions/cache/save@v3](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/save/README.md).
You can restore or save cache separately.